# Axios + NUXT ..How to update browser url with 'slug' data from API and Update my Base Url in axios in my page for get new data to show

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I'm trying to update the browser URL after I click on the link of a profile which sends me to a "_slug" page dedicated for profile because the name of the profile is in the API data slug.

And after I'm trying to find a way to update my Axios "API url" which is in profile page with the slug data from my first API:

```
 async mounted() {
  await axios.get("####" + slug from the first API)
.then(response => {this.results = response.data.content})
```

like this I could fill up my page with the right data.

Comment: Hi! I'm trying to understand what you want to achieve. So you have a list of profiles on a page, and want to link to some sort of detailpage when you click on one? So for example you're on /profiles and when clicked on a profile you want to change the URL to /profiles/john ?

Comment: Yes its exactly that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the Nuxt routing is very smart at reading your folder structure. When you want to make routes you have to follow the folder structure mentioned [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/get-started/routing). You are looking for dynamic routing. So you don't know the route but you know it should be a name, UUID for example.

For making dynamic routes you will have in your `pages/` folder a folder called `person/` and in this folder, you will make a file called `_id.vue`. What this means is: if you set a dynamic id after person, it will call this file.

Within this file, you can then pull all the data you need in the mounted method. you can access the route and it's params, will contain `id`. Via that, you can access your store if you have, or make the Axios request with the specific id needed to load the correct data.

I found this tutorial on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjAdDQAuOcU).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help i follow the tutorial ... i could get the url i wanted and pages are create dynamically thats great ... now im looking for a way to call the API in my _id.vue page  but the things is the API url is different from each person  its like : http######.com/women/slug (slug is from the another API link i put on other page

Comment: Can't you make the _id in the URL the slug you need in your API call? If not you can also add a query param. It isn't the most beautiful solution but it will work. Another thing you could do is when the click on a page is done, fire an event that stores the slug in your store. When the _id page is loaded, read that value from your store and paste it into the URL of your API call.

Comment: Thank you RikLamers for your help :) unfortunally i cant make the ID in url the slug ..so now im trying to use a query param like : 
axios.get('######', {
    params: {
      name: result.slug ( result.slug come from my first API call but maybe i need to make this call on thr page" _ID.vue" too for get the slug and put it dynammically in the url of my second APi call }
    }
  })